# yq expression to recursively force array

Tags: xml, yaml, yq

https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/ can convert xml files to json.

`data.xml` which looks like:

```
<root>
  <heading>
    <member>one</member>
  </heading>
  <heading>
    <member>two</member>
    <member>three</member>
  </heading>
</root>
```

Running `yq --input-format xml . data.xml` outputs:

```
root:
  heading:
    - member: one
    - member:
        - two
        - three
```

`member` is outputted with two different types. After some digging I found:

> "yq assumes consecutive nodes with the same name are assumed to be
> arrays. If there's only one node with a name, yq assumes its a map"

https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/1583

So we can modify the query to be `yq --input-format xml '.root.heading.[].member |= [] + .'  data.xml` which outputs:

```
root:
  heading:
    - member:
        - one
    - member:
        - two
        - three
```

However this requires passing the **exact path** and **key name** for **every override**, and assumes you **know the hierarchy of nodes in advance**.

I am handling files handcoded by users, and the nesting is different for every file.
I need a more dynamic yq expression which can match multiple map keys at any level.

yq has a Recursive Descent (Glob) operator
https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/recursive-descent-glob

So far I have a query:
`yq --input-format xml '(... | select(key == "member")) |= [] + .' data.xml` which outputs:

```
root:
  heading:
    -? - member
      : - one
    -? - member
      : - two
        - three
```

However it does not output the result I would expect. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you actually only want to glob the value nodes (then test if their `key` matches certain criteria), but you don't want to glob the key nodes themselves. Thus, use `..` instead of `...`:

```bash
yq --input-format xml '(.. | select(key == "member")) |= [] + .' data.xml
```

```yaml
root:
  heading:
    - member:
        - one
    - member:
        - two
        - three
```

Comment: I was so close, thank-you for the swift answer. To support multiple keys you can do: `yq --input-format xml '(.. | select(key == "member" or key == "item")) |= [] + .' data.xml`

Comment: Interestingly if you use an `or` operator with `parent/child` nodes then the parent doesn't get converted. Unsure if that is a bug: `yq --input-format xml '(.. | select(key == "heading" or key == "member")) |= [] + .' data.xml`

Comment: Same happens if you try and convert all maps to arrays: `yq --input-format xml '(.. | select(tag == "!!map")) |= [] + .' data.xml`

Comment: Opened an issue when converting parent/child arrays here: https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/1708